# Restore Windows to factory settings on a Dell computer

Tags: windows-xp, bsod

I have a Dell computer that has the Blue Screen of Death. I booted from Puppy Linux non-PAE to retrieve files. Now I wish to restore Windows. I have been following instructions from [this site](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/7319-dell-inspiron-restore-to-factory-default-settings#for-vista-or-win-7). I made it to step 3, but I don't see the option to "Repair Your Computer." The closest thing is Directory Services Restore Mode (Windows domain controllers only). When I selected that and then the operation system, which is the only choice, I get the BSoD.

The computer runs Windows XP, but I used the sites' Vista/7 section, because they were the only ones that worked.

Of course, if the BSod can be fixed without restoring it to factory setting, I'd be happy to do it. The error code is: `Stop: 0x000000ED (0x837D76B0,0xC0000006,0x00000000,0x00000000)`

Oh and safe mode does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If CTRL and F11 don't work, then you have lost the 'factory restore' partition on the hard drive ..

If that laptop has a CD/DVD drive, set the 'boot order' in the BIOS to CD/DVD first and you will need a Dell 'OEM' bootable Windows XP disc ...

If not, you will need XP on a a bootable USB stick ..

NOTE - Dell OEM XP discs are all 'identical' .... the Dell OEM Licence is in the BIOS (you won't need to ender the Licence code) .. so you can just copy any XP disc you can find - note that early versions of Dell OEM XPsp2 versions were not bootable, so be careful if you buy on eBay (ideally you want XP sp3) .. if you get 'stuck' with a non-bootable sp2 it is possible to make a copy and add the boot blocks before 'burning' ...

Comment: Or contact Dell for a CD. That used to be only €5 (at least when ordered with the computer so no extra shipping was involved). OR ask IT at work for a copy. I think the last is legal because to already have a legal license, though that can vary per country.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously windows is corrupted and you need to reinstall the entire os, recovery is not possible.

Make sure you recovered all your files before you do this because xp does not install over another windows installations like Vista or 7, and now 8.

Comment: How do I re install os if I don't have the cd

Comment: You need complete this question, and ask a new question with your laptop's details and what the situation is.

Comment: It is included above. Do you happen to know wy I don't see the repair computer option, or is the related the os being corrupted?

Comment: @taapsogeking your operating is corrupted, this question is not going to be solved unless you reinstall windows. You're running a 10+ year old operating system, the repair options are extremely limited. When Xp glitches its basically done for.

Comment: Maybe a tad pessimistic, but yeah. XP is old. Main support ended in **2009** (5 years ago). [Extended support will end in 2014](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/products/lifecycle). Still, it can be used for another half year.